# How to check the Android developer tools version from the command line?

Tags: android, command-line, adt

I'm trying to retrieve the ADT version to generate some system reports.

How can I check the version of the android developer tools installed on the system using the command line?

Comment: The formal name seems to be "Android SDK Tools"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Various parts of the tools save their revision number in files

For example

```
cat /android/sdk/platform-tools/source.properties | grep Pkg.Revision
cat /android/sdk/tools/source.properties | grep Pkg.Revision
```

The build tools themselves are placed in versioned directories, so you can find them via

```
ls /android/sdk/build-tools/
```